# Help with an introduction to differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am taking linear methods this year and im trying to get some more review for differential equations. This is a problem that I ran across:

a) Show that the constant function y(x) = 0, for all x, is a solution of this differential equation.

b)  Solve this differential equation with the initial condition y(0) = 0. Is your answer for this part consistent with the first part?

$$(x^2+1)(dy/dx) = 2xy^2$$

I believe I can get as far as

$$y = 1/(ln(x^2+1)+C) $$

but then $y(0) = 0$ would make it undefined?

Any help or hints? I just cant pick up the concept of diff equations.

Thanks
Will

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you supposed to show $y(x)=0$ is a solution to $\frac{dy}{dx}(x^2+1) = 2xy^2$

Answer (score 0):

The steps in your work assume that y is not zero, so you do not have the entire general solution!  If you plug y(0) = 0 directly in the the differential equation, you get $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$.  So for this initial condition you have a constant solution of y = 0.